# Adicionar volumenes y ficheros a un contenedor en Azure usando Pulumi

Tags: azure

Estoy comenzando a usar Pulumi para el despliegue de contenedores en Azure cloud.
Por el momento estoy confrontando problemas pues necesito cargar algunos ficheros de configuracion a un contenedor de traefik pero no encuentro el modo correcto. La idea es que Traefik funcione como un Proxy reverso de los demas contenedores del grupo.

MI problema es que por mas que especifico la crecion de un volumen y intento conectarlo al contenedor, cuando voy al dashboard de Azure, aparece como que el contenedor no tiene ningun volumen conectado.

Aca les comparte el codigo

```
import pulumi
import pulumi_azure_nextgen as azure

data_rg = azure.resources.latest.ResourceGroup(
       "data-rg",
       resource_group_name="data-rg",
       location="West Europe")
datahike_group = azure.containerinstance.latest.ContainerGroup(
        "data-group",
        location="West Europe",
        container_group_name="data-cg",
        resource_group_name=data_rg.name,
        containers=[{
                    "name":"data",
                    "image": "wordpress:latest",
                    "resources": {
                        "requests": { "cpu": 0.5, "memory_in_gb": 1.5}
                    },
                },
                {
                    "name": "proxy",
                    "image": "traefik:latest",
                    "resources": {
                        "requests": { "cpu": 0.5, "memory_in_gb": 1.5}
                    },
                    "ports": [{
                        "port": 80,
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        }],
                    "VolumeMount": [{
                        "mount_path": "/etc/traefik/config_base.yml",
                        "name": "traefik-volume",
                    }],
                    "environment_variables": [{
                        "name": "TRAEFIK_CONFIG_FILE",
                        "value": "file"
                        },{
                        "name": "TRAEFIK_CONFIG_PATH",
                        "value": "/etc/traefik/config_base.yml"
                        }
                    ],                    
                },        
        ],
        ip_address={
            "dnsNameLabel": "dnsnamelabel1",
            "ports": [{
                "port": 80,
                "protocol": "TCP",
            }],
            "type": "Public",
        },
        volumes=[
            {
                "emptyDir": {},
                "name": "datahike-volume",
            },
            {
                "name": "traefik-volume",
                "secret": {
                    "secretKey1": "SecretValue1InBase64",
                },
            },            
        ],
        os_type="Linux",
        tags={
            "environment": "testing",
        })

pulumi.export("data_ip", data_group.ip_address)
```

Alguien sabe que esta faltando?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente di con la respuesta.

El modo correcto de hacerlo es usando:

**volumeMounts**

y no

**VolumeMount**